# Mask a prefilled number with jQuery-Mask-Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a input type=number. I am using the [jQuery-Mask-Plugin](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin) for masking.
It works well when I enter a number.

How do I trigger the mask function if the input field already contains a number?

Currently, if the input already contains a number, the lib does not mask it but as soon as I edit the number, it starts masking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the field already has a value in it:

```
$("input[type=number]").mask("00/00/0000").trigger("keyup");
```

Comment: So the masking does not get triggered on keyup. Its when you start entering some value into the field.

Comment: Did you try it?  There are different ways to check "when you start entering some value".  One of them is https://api.jquery.com/keyup/, and that is what this plugin uses.

Comment: Oh ok. But yes, I tired it. I also tried it with keypress and keydown.

Comment: It did work. The mask function was applied before my DOM was loaded.